# Invoke a c++ class method without a class instance?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to invoke a `c++` class method without first creating a class instance?

Suppose we have the following code:

```
// just an example 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass();
        ~MyClass();
        int MyMethod(int *a, int *b);
};

// just a dummy method
int MyClass::MyMethod(int *a, int *b){;
    return a[0] - b[0];
}
```

---

**Here's another example:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClassAnother {
    public:
        MyClassAnother();
        ~MyClassAnother();
        int MyMethod(int *a, int *b);
};

// just a dummy method
int MyClassAnother::MyMethod(int *a, int *b){;
    return a[0] + b[0];
}
```

As we can see, in the above examples, both classes have no internal variables and use dummy constructors / destructors; *Their sole purpose is to expose one public method*, `MyMethod(..)`. Here's my question: assume there are 100 such classes in the file (all with different class names, but with an identical structure -- one public method having the same prototype -- `MyMethod(..)`.

Is there a way to invoke the `MyMethod(..)` method calls of each one of the classes without first creating a class instance for each?

Comment: How about making `MyMethod` static? http://www.functionx.com/cppcli/classes/Lesson12b.htm

Comment: And do you really need the constructor/destructor? Hey, why not just use a free function in the first place?

Comment: @Keith -- I don't need the constructor/destructor. But, I do need to have all the methods named `MyFunction()` -- so, in order to differentiate between the different methods, I am wrapping them in different classes; Do you have a better idea how to achieve that functionality while still having them all named `MyFunction()`?

Comment: @rjz -- thank you. That seems to be the way. Now, just to make sure, if both classes have another method, `Helper(...)`, and that `Helper(...)` is called *from within* both `MyMethod(...)` methods, each `MyMethod(...)` will invoke its *own* `Helper(...)` method, right? meaning, it will invoke the `Helper(...)` that belongs to the same class, correct?

Comment: what is this feature used for?

Comment: You could also just use namespaces.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use the keyword 'static' to declare the method:

```
static int MyMethod( int * a, int * b );
```

Then you can call the method without an instance like so:

```
int one = 1;
int two = 2;

MyClass::MyMethod( &two, &one );
```

'static' methods are functions which only use the class as a namespace, and do not require an instance.

Comment: @Greyson -- thank you! So basically, going the `static` route, I will be able to define 100s of classes + `MyMethod()` methods and invoke them without class instances, right? MyClass1::MyMethod( &two, &one ); MyClass2::MyMethod( &two, &one ); ............... MyClass3::MyMethod( &two, &one );    Did I get it right?

Comment: Correct.  If this is going to be a utility class, I suggest making the constructor `private` so that there is no mistake that this class is not meant to be instantiated.

Comment: @Greyson -- yes, I really don't need neither the constructor nor the destructor here; However, I do plan to have 1000s of such classes wrapped in one utility file -- is that a good practice? are there better way to achieve this while still being able to name all of these methods `MyMethod(...)`?

Comment: In order to judge if having hundreds of one-static-method classes is a good practice, I would need a bit more context. What are you trying to accomplish by using the same method name?

Comment: First, I think I will end up with thousands, or even tens of thousands; Second, the main reason for this is not to have to initialize a class instance every time I want to invoke a `MyMethod(...)` call; This will be used in a time-sensitive app that will use 10000s of such methods -- I thought it would be a waste if I need to instantiate a class before each such a call. What do you think? Will I have memory issues?

Comment: No, It won't use up a substantially greater amount of memory to use static class methods rather than free functions. Making them static will save you memory and time over non-static.

Comment: So is it a good idea to go the `static` route? How much memory (approx.) is used for each such a method? will it be a problem -- in terms of memory -- to have 10000s such classes (each containing its own `MyMethod(...)`? thanks for all of your help.

Comment: is there a way to use it without the scope resolution operator? like std::cout -> using namespace std; -> cout
is there something like
MyClass::MyMethod() -> using class MyClass; -> MyMethod()?

Answer (score 5):

You can call a class method without an instance by declaring it `static`, but that doesn't appear to be what you want. You want to be able to call the same method on 100 different classes.

There are two ways for C++ to differentiate between different class methods. One is to do it at compile time, and one is to do it at run time. At compile time you need to invoke the class name itself as part of the call on a static method, or you need the object instance or pointer to be to a specific derived class. At run time you can call a method polymorphically if you have declared the method virtual. Note that you need an object of the class to use either of the run-time methods.

Comment: yes, I want to call the same *method name* -- `MyMethod()`. Yet, each class will have a different implementation for `MyMethod()`. Will declaring it *static* help me call the various `MyMethod()` methods, while each time invoking a different class / implementation?

Comment: @user58925, no, declaring it `static` will make it impossible to use the method polymorphically. You need to declare it `virtual`, but then you must also call it from an instance of the class. No way around it.

Comment: I am not sure I am clarifying myself properly; Basically, ideally I would want to define the `MyMethod()` methods as *free functions* (without classes); Yet, this will force me to give each such a function a different name, and thus, in order to simplify the process, it makes sense to me to simple use the same name (`MyFunction`) while wrapping each one of these in a unique class; How is `virtual` going to help in the case illustrated above? thanks!

Comment: @user58925, effectively each static function gets a different name because you must prefix them with the class name. `MyClass1::MyMethod` is different from `MyClass2::MyMethod`. When it's virtual you can use an object to differentiate them and the calling code need not be aware of which method will get called. `myArray[0] = new MyClass1; myArray[1] = new MyClass2; myArray[0]->MyMethod(a, b); myArray[1]->MyMethod(a, b);`

Comment: Thank you Mark. What would be the benefit of defining the methods as *virtual* Vs. the approach suggested by @dasblinkenlight below (which only uses *static* to define the method)? thank you for all of your help!

Comment: @user58925, the benefit is that you don't need some artificial way of selecting which method to use, it's determined by the type of the object. If in your case you would need some artificial means of creating the proper object, this advantage would be negated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why no one else mentioned this, but from the functionality described in your comments, **it sounds like what you want is a namespace, not a class**. It's perfectly fine for you to have 100 functions with the same name defined in 100 differently named namespaces. It should behave exactly as you are describing, and is the entire purpose behind namespaces.

Comment: The only reason I could see that the OP may have wanted to use `class`/`struct` instead is to pass them as template arguments. Other than that, your answer really should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Random and Greyson mentioned, you can make that method static, and then invoke the right signature without instantiating an object. However, you may want to think twice about writing your function this way rather than writing a different version of that same function. Here are the considerations, especially for a large program:

- static methods are **difficult to write unit tests for**.
- B/c of the nature of static methods, they reside in the memory **all the time**.
- Multithreading would be difficult if your program needs to utilize it.

Comment: thank you. The truth is, I will have 1000s of such classes in a utility file, and will need to call *all* the `MyMethod(...)` methods at some point or another; I really don't want to have to create an instance each time before calling a `MyMethod(...)` -- hence, I thought that `static` is the way to go. Do you have a better suggestion / alternative to this?

Comment: any idea how much memory (approx) each of the `MyMethod(...)` can take?  Will it be a memory problem if I have 1000s of such methods in memory?

Comment: What's hard about writing a test for a static method? It's about the same as a free function. It's hard if you assume you have to make a subclass in order to test, but that is not the right approach for a method that does share the invariant of the class state.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group functions together under a named scope, then you'd be better off with a `namespace`. You can access functions of a namespace with the scope resolution operator `::`

```
namespace my_namespace {
  int my_function(int *a, int *b) {
    return a[0] + b[0];
  }
}

int main() {
  int* arr1 = /* ... */
  int* arr2 = /* ... */
  my_namespace::my_function(arr1, arr2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeap. You definitely shouldn't do this in production code, but in this case you can call class method using empty pointer and it will work. Technically you don't create a class instance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass();
        ~MyClass();
        int MyMethod(int *a, int *b);
};

// just a dummy method
int MyClass::MyMethod(int *a, int *b){;
    return a[0] - b[0];
}

int main() {
    MyClass *myClass = nullptr;
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    std::cout << res = myClass->MyMethod(&a, &b) << std::endl;
}
```

Wubba Lubba dub-dub!

Comment: Suggestions: change `res = myClass->` to `myClass->`, and maybe get rid of `using namesapce std`? Also, any chance you've got any links to show why this actually works? I'd happily upvote this as an interesting quirk of the language.

Comment: I think this is undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can call a function of an uninstantiated object--but don't expect to be able to refer to any of the objects members (they don't exist).

IDK why it works. Its definitely got some bad code smell. Agreed that static functions is better, but this is still interesting.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class foo
{
public:
    void print() {std::cout<<"Hello World" <<std::endl;}
    int m_val;
};

int main ()
{
    std::shared_ptr<foo> p1;
    p1->print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior, sanitizers will yell at you if you do this: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cYc88EGzh

Comment: Also, the answers should be self-contained. I suggest copying the code from the link into the answer as text.